# Wordpress 5.0 automatic link all images to media file

Tags: php, api, gallery, wordpress-gutenberg

I had small problem after WP 5.0 released, I was using php snippet to out all the gallery images Linked to "media file" automatically and two columns with  medium size, but the function stopped working.

any ideas how can i make it work again with WP 5.0 Gutenberg! 
Thanks in advance.

here is the old snippet.

```
function amethyst_gallery_atts( $out, $pairs, $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'columns' => '2',
        'size' => 'medium',
        'link' => 'file',
         ), $atts );

    $out['columns'] = $atts['columns'];
    $out['size'] = $atts['size'];
    $out['link'] = $atts['link'];

    return $out;

}
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery', 'amethyst_gallery_atts', 10, 3 );
```